# ArangoDB Java Driver Caching Not Working

Tags: java, caching, arangodb

I was trying to implement the query cache for large queries in ArangoDB.

When i check if the document cursor is cached or not, it shows that the cache is true. But i see no performance improvements in the query time processing.

However using the same query from arangodb web interface shows high performance improvements due to caching.

> **Edit :**
>
> Java Driver Version: **2.7.4**
>
> ArangoDb Version: **2.8.7**
>
> My Query is:
>
> ```
> for t in MyStorage FILTER t.myDate>'2016-01-11' and t.myDate<'2016-06-01' and t.fraud!=null and t.fraud!='' and t.currency=='INR' return {myID:t.myID,myDate:t.myDate,amount:t.amount,fraud:t.fraud}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tested Caching with the following Testcase and saw a performance improvement. 
Can you post an example of your query?

```
public class ArangoDriverCacheTest {

    private static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "unitTestCollection";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "unitTestDatabase";
    private static ArangoConfigure configure;
    private static ArangoDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws ArangoException {

        configure = new ArangoConfigure();
        configure.init();
        driver = new ArangoDriver(configure);

        // // create test database
        try {
            driver.createDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        } catch (final ArangoException e) {
        }
        driver.setDefaultDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

        // create test collection
        try {
            driver.createCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);
        } catch (final ArangoException e) {
        }
        driver.truncateCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);

        // create some test data
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            final TestEntity value = new TestEntity("user_" + (i % 10), "desc" + (i % 10), i);
            driver.createDocument(COLLECTION_NAME, value);
        }

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdown() {
        try {
            driver.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        } catch (final ArangoException e) {
        }
        configure.shutdown();
    }

    private AqlQueryOptions createAqlQueryOptions(
        final Boolean count,
        final Integer batchSize,
        final Boolean fullCount,
        final Boolean cache) {
        return new AqlQueryOptions().setCount(count).setBatchSize(batchSize).setFullCount(fullCount).setCache(cache);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_withoutCache() throws ArangoException {
        // set cache mode off
        final QueryCachePropertiesEntity properties = new QueryCachePropertiesEntity();
        properties.setMode("off");
        driver.setQueryCacheProperties(properties);

        exceuteQuery(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_withCache() throws ArangoException {
        // set cache mode on
        final QueryCachePropertiesEntity properties = new QueryCachePropertiesEntity();
        properties.setMode("on");
        driver.setQueryCacheProperties(properties);

        // set caching to true for the query
        exceuteQuery(true);
    }

    private void exceuteQuery(final boolean cache) throws ArangoException {

        final AqlQueryOptions aqlQueryOptions = createAqlQueryOptions(true, 1000, null, cache);
        final String query = "FOR t IN " + COLLECTION_NAME + " FILTER t.age >= @age SORT t.age RETURN t";
        final Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("age", 90).get();

        DocumentCursor<TestEntity> rs = driver.executeDocumentQuery(query, bindVars, aqlQueryOptions, TestEntity.class);
        // first time, the query isn't cached
        Assert.assertEquals(false, rs.isCached());

        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // query the cached value
        rs = driver.executeDocumentQuery(query, bindVars, aqlQueryOptions, TestEntity.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(cache, rs.isCached());

        // load all results
        rs.asEntityList();

        final long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(String.format("time with cache=%s: %sms", cache, time));
    }

    private static class TestEntity {
        private final String user;
        private final String desc;
        private final Integer age;

        public TestEntity(final String user, final String desc, final Integer age) {
            super();
            this.user = user;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, i am getting some issues while running this test. aqlQueryOptions.getCache() returns null even if i set it to true manually again in the test. Moreover, the result in both cases (with and without cache) is almost the same. Hardly 1-2 millisecond gap.

Comment: i changed my code, now it's arango2.8/driver2.7 compatible.
The getter aqlQueryOptions.getCache() has a bug, it's returns the wront member.

When I run this test, I get following outpunt:
`time with cache=true: 7396ms`
`time with cache=false: 13703ms`

Comment: Works for me. The problem was with the batch size in Default Query Options. Can you suggest me the optimal batch size for queries returning a large number of documents?

Comment: It highly depends on your document size. The server can cache 500MB. The BatchSize in the Driver represents the number of documents. So you can pick `500MB / DocumentSizeMB = BatchSize`